# R function to obtain the t-stat value from a t-test of already normalized data

Tags: r

As suggested by you I'm going to provide a more complete script and explanation of my data.
So, I have microarray gene expression data that I downloaded from a article published in Bioinformatics that comprises on the RUV-normalization of several microarray datasets (I provide the head() of my data below). Therefore, the data I possess has already been normalized. To do diferential expression analysis I performed t-test between two groups A and B for all genes present in my panel using the compare_means() function, as the code below shows.

My objective with this analysis is to perform GSEA analysis that will differentiate between the normal tissue and the tumor tissue in the dataset regarding their immunologic proporties.

When searching how to do this I found the fgsea package that ends up only needing the T-value for each gene comparison to perform the GSEA analysis. However the compare_means() does not provide the T-value of the test, which I need. I am new to R and from my research there are the functions t.test() and t_test() that can give me this result, however I do not know how to apply these functions to make the test on all genes at once as I did with compare_means(). Could you provide me with some solution for this problem either it is a for_loop or another package? It is important to note that I believe the fgsea package is the one best fitted for my purposes because I want to see both the enriched and decreased pathways.

I also found that it would be best to perform limma() analysis on the raw data and then apply those results to the gsea analysis (what is also your opinion on this matter?). I don't know if I have access to the raw data, that is something I have to sort out. Even If I have it is reported that the raw merged data has batch variations that are only removed after the RUV-normalization.

So, the code I used to perform the differential expression follows below:

```
> dput(data[1:10, 1:5])
structure(list(Patients = c("Patient0", "Patient1", "Patient2", 
"Patient3", "Patient4", "Patient5", "Patient6", "Patient7", "Patient8", 
"Patient9"), A2M = c(0.2895, 1.2463, -0.1309, -0.8332, -0.5526, 
0.0017, 0.6156, 0.2293, -0.4436, -0.587), ABCB1 = c(0.5023, 1.2426, 
-0.5671, -0.5815, -0.1716, 1.123, 0.3743, 0.0532, 0.1204, 1.1584
), ABCF1 = c(0.0848, 0.5559, 0.1182, 0.0412, -0.0118, 0.1299, 
0.2574, -0.0514, -0.1118, 0.1633), ACKR2 = c(-0.0767, 0.2744, 
0.3907, -0.3495, 0.0176, 0.2393, 0.0155, -0.4302, -0.1493, -0.5265
)), row.names = c("Patient0", "Patient1", "Patient2", "Patient3", 
"Patient4", "Patient5", "Patient6", "Patient7", "Patient8", "Patient9"
), class = "data.frame")
```

```
teste1 <- compare_means(formula = c(A2M,ABCB1,ABCF1,ACKR2,ADA,ADGRE2,AGK,AICDA,AIRE,AKT3,ALAS1,ALCAM,AMBP,AMM,ECR1L,ANP32B,ANXA1,APOE,APP,ARG2,ATG12,ATG16L1,ATG5,ATG7,ATM,AXL,BATF,BAX,BCL2,BCL2L1,BCL6,BID,BIRC5,BLK,BLNK,BST2,BTK,BTLA,C1D,C1QA,C1QBP,C1R,C1S,C3,C3AR1,C4BPB,C5,C8A,C8B,C8G,CARD11,CASP1,CASP10,CASP3,CC2D1B,CCL1,CCL11,CCL13,CCL16,CCL17,CCL18,CCL19,CCL2,CCL20,CCL21,CCL22,CCL23,CCL24,CCL25,CCL26,CCL5,CCL7,CCL8,CCM2,CCND3,CCR1,CCR2,CCR3,CCR4,CCR6,CCR7,CCRL2,CD160,CD163,CD180,CD19,CD1A,CD1B,CD1E,CD2,CD200,CD207,CD24,CD244,CD247,CD27,CD276,CD28,CD33,CD34,CD36,CD37,CD38,CD3D,CD3E,CD4,CD40,CD40LG,CD44,CD46,CD47,CD48,CD5,CD53,CD55,CD58,CD59,CD6,CD63,CD68,CD7,CD70,CD74,CD79A,CD79B,CD80,CD81,CD83,CD86,CD8A,CD8B,CD9,CD96,CD99,CDH5,CEACAM1,CEACAM6,CEACAM8,CEBPB,CFI,CFP,CHAMP1,CHUK,CLEC4A,CLEC4C,CLEC5A,CLEC7A,CLSTN1,CLU,CMA1,CMKLR1,CNOT10,CNOT4,COG7,COL3A1,COLEC12,CR1,CR2,CREB1,CREB5,CSF1,CSF1R,CSF2RB,CSF3,CSF3R,CSRP1,CTAGE1,CTCFL,CTLA4,CTSG,CTSH,CTSL,CTSS,CTSW,CX3CL1,CX3CR1,CXCL1,CXCL10,CXCL11,CXCL12,CXCL13,CXCL14,CXCL16,CXCL2,CXCL3,CXCL5,CXCL6,CXCL8,CXCL9,CXCR1,CXCR2,CXCR3,CXCR4,CXCR5,CXCR6,CXXC1,CYBB,CYFIP2,CYLD,DDX43,DDX50,DEFB1,DHX16,DMBT1,DNAJC14,DOCK9,DPP4,DUSP4,DUSP6,EBI3,ECSIT,EDC3,EGR1,EGR2,EIF2B4,ELANE,ENC1,ENG,ENTPD1,EOMES,EP300,EPCAM,ERCC3,ETS1,EWSR1,F12,F13A1,FADD,FASN,FCER1A,FCER1G,FCER2,FCF1,FCGR2A,FLT3,FLT3LG,FN1,FOS,FOXJ1,FOXP3,FPR2,FUT5,FUT7,FYN,FZR1,GATA3,GCHFR,GDNF,GNLY,GNPDA1,GPATCH3,GTF3C1,GUSB,GZMA,GZMB,GZMH,GZMK,GZMM,HAMP,HAVCR2,HDAC3,HLA.DMA,HLA.DMB,HLA.DOB,HLA.DPA1,HPRT1,HSD11B1,ICAM1,ICAM2,ICAM3,ICAM4,ICOS,IDO1,IFI16,IFI35,IFIH1,IFIT1,IFIT2,IFITM1,IFITM2,IFNA2,IFNA8,IFNAR1,IFNB1,IFNG,IFNGR1,IFNL1,IFNL2,IGF1,IGF2R,IGLL1,IKBKB,IKBKE,IKBKG,IL10,IL10RA,IL11,IL11RA,IL12B,IL12RB1,IL12RB2,IL13RA1,IL13RA2,IL15,IL15RA,IL16,IL17B,IL17RA,IL17RB,IL18,IL18R1,IL18RAP,IL19,IL1A,IL1B,IL1R1,IL1R2,IL1RAP,IL1RAPL2,IL1RL1,IL1RL2,IL1RN,IL2,IL21,IL21R,IL22,IL22RA1,IL22RA2,IL23A,IL23R,IL24,IL26,IL2RA,IL2RB,IL2RG,IL32,IL34,IL4,IL4R,IL5,IL5RA,IL6,IL6R,IL7)
                        ~ design.design, data = data, method = "t.test", p.adjust.method = "fdr")

teste1 <- rbind(teste1)
```

```
teste2 <- compare_means(formula = c(IL7R,ILF3,INPP5D,IRAK1,IRAK2,IRAK4,IRF2,IRF3,IRF4,IRF5,IRF7,IRF8,ITCH,ITGA2,ITGA2B,ITGA4,ITGA5,ITGA6,ITGAE,ITGAL,ITGAM,ITGAX,ITGB1,ITGB3,ITGB4,ITK,JAK1,JAK2,JAK3,JAM3,JAML,KCNH8,KIT,KLRB1,KLRD1,KLRF1,LAG3,LAMP3,LCK,LCN2,LGALS3,LIF,LILRA1,LILRA4,LILRA5,LILRB1,LILRB2,LRPPRC,LRRN3,LTB,LTBR,LTF,LTK,LY9,LYN,LZTS1,MAF,MAGEA1,MAGEB2,MAGEC1,MAGEC2,MAP2K1,MAP2K2,MAP2K4,MAP3K1,MAP3K5,MAP3K7,MAP4K2,MAPK1,MAPK11,MAPK14,MAPK8,MAPKAPK2,MARCO,MASP1,MASP2,MAVS,MBL2,MCAM,MEF2C,MEFV,MFGE8,MME,MNX1,MR1,MRC1,MRPS5,MS4A1,MS4A2,MSR1,MST1R,MTMR14,MX1,MYD88,MYDGF,NANOS2,NCAM1,NCF4,NDUFA2,NEFL,NELL1,NFATC1,NFATC2,NFATC3,NFATC4,NFKB1,NFKB2,NFKBIA,NLRP3,NOD1,NOD2,NOL7,NOTCH1,NR1I2,NT5E,NUBP2,NUP107,OAS3,PAG1,PAX5,PBK,PDCD1LG2,PDGFC,PDGFRB,PDZD2,PECAM1,PGAP1,PIK3CG,PIKFYVE,PLA2G1B,PLA2G6,PLAU,PLAUR,PMCH,PNMA1,POLD1,POLR1G,POLR2A,POU2AF1,POU2F2,PPARG,PPBP,PPIA,PPP1R9B,PRAME,PRKCD,PRKCE,PRPF38A,PSEN1,PSEN2,PSMA7,PSMB10,PSMD7,PTGDR2,PTGS2,PTPRC,PVR,PXDN,PXDNL,PYCARD,RAG1,REL,RELB,REPS1,RIPK2,RORA,RPS27A,RPS6,RRAD,RUNX1,RUNX3,S100A12,S100B,SBNO2,SDHA,SEC14L2,SELE,SELL,SELPLG,SEMG1,SERPINB2,SERPING1,SF3A3,SF3B3,SH2B2,SH2D1A,SH2D1B,SIGLEC1,SLAMF7,SMAD2,SMAD3,SMPD3,SOCS1,SPA17,SPACA3,SPANXB1,SPINK5,SPO11,SSX1,ST6GAL1,STAT1,STAT2,STAT3,STAT4,STAT5B,STAT6,SYCP1,SYK,SYT17,TAL1,TANK,TAPBP,TBK1,TBP,TBX21,TCEAL1,TCF7,TFEB,TFRC,TGFB1,TGFB2,THBD,THBS1,THY1,TICAM1,TINAGL1,TIRAP,TLR1,TLR10,TLR3,TLR4,TLR5,TLR6,TLR7,TLR8,TLR9,TMED5,TMUB2,TNF,TNFAIP3,TNFRSF10B,TNFRSF11A,TNFRSF11B,TNFRSF12A,TNFRSF13B,TNFRSF13C,TNFRSF14,TNFRSF17,TNFRSF18,TNFRSF1A,TNFRSF1B,TNFRSF4,TNFRSF8,TNFRSF9,TNFSF10,TNFSF11,TNFSF13B,TNFSF14,TNFSF15,TNFSF18,TNFSF4,TNFSF8,TOLLIP,TOX4,TPTE,TRAF3,TRAF6,TREM1,TREM2,TTK,TUBB2A,TXK,TXNIP,TYK2,UBL4A,USP39,USP9Y,VCAM1,VEGFA,VEGFC,XCR1,YTHDF2,ZAP70,ZC3H14,ZKSCAN5,ZNF143,ZNF205,ZNF395,ZNRD2)
                        ~ design.design, data = data, method = "t.test", p.adjust.method = "fdr")

teste2 <- rbind(teste2)
```

```
ttest_results <- rbind(teste1, teste2)
rownames(ttest_results) <- ttest_results$.y.
write.xlsx(ttest_results, "ttest_G4vsNormal_results.xlsx", rowNames = TRUE)
```

------------ Once you have done the t.test you can come back later and start here
#2. Aplicar o script de fold change, mas com o file de t-test para todos os genes, obtido antes

```
data <- read.xlsx("Gene_Table.xlsx", rowNames = TRUE, sheet = 1)
```

Upload again the traits table and create again the column with the respective subgroups designation

```
# For the subgroup versus non-tumor samples analysis

class <- read.xlsx("traits.xlsx")
rownames(class) <- class$ID
class <- class[,-1]

class$class[class$WNT==2] <- "WNT"
class$class[class$SHH==2] <- "SHH"
class$class[class$Group3==2] <- "Group3"
class$class[class$Group4==2] <- "Group4"
class$class[class$Non_Tumor==2] <- "Non_Tumor"
```

```
# For the tumor versus non-tumor samples analysis

class <- read.xlsx("traits.xlsx", sheet = 2)
rownames(class) <- class$ID
class <- class[,-1]

class$design[class$Tumor==2] <- "Medulloblastoma"
class$design[class$Non_Tumor==2] <- "Non_Tumor"
```

Select the subgroup and the non-tumor samples

```
class_G4 <- subset(class, class %in% c("Non_Tumor", "Group4"))
patients <- rownames(class_G4)
data_G4 <- data[match(patients, rownames(data)),]
data_G4 <- t(data_G4)
```

```
statistic <- read.xlsx("ttest_G4vsNORMAL_results.xlsx", rowNames = TRUE)
genes <- unique(statistic$.y.)
#data <- t(data)
#data.filter <- data[match(genes,rownames(data)),]
#data.filter <- data.frame(data.filter)
#data.filter <- t(data.filter)
```

```
First <- subset(class, class == "Group4")
First <- rownames(First)
avg.G4 <- apply(data_G4[,First], 1, mean)

second <- subset(class, class == "Non_Tumor")
second <- rownames(second)
avg.NonTumor <- apply(data_G4[,second], 1, mean)
```

```
fc <- data.frame(genes, avg.G4, avg.NonTumor, row.names = rownames(data_G4)) %>%
  mutate(LOG2Fc = avg.G4 - avg.NonTumor) %>% mutate(statistic$p) %>% mutate(statistic$p.adj)
fc <- fc[,-1]
write.xlsx(fc, "G4_Fchange_for_volcano.xlsx", rowNames = TRUE) #save the file in order to be able to use it in the next script chunks without the need to run all the code
```

Install the Volcano plot package. This package produces publication ready volcano plots

```
if (!requireNamespace('BiocManager', quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages('BiocManager')

BiocManager::install('EnhancedVolcano')
library(EnhancedVolcano)
```

## Group 4 vs NORMAL

```
fc <- read.xlsx("G4_Fchange_for_volcano.xlsx", rowNames = TRUE)

png("Volcano_G4vsNonTumor.png", width = 30, height = 30, res = 300, units = "cm")
EnhancedVolcano(fc,
                lab = rownames(fc),
                x = 'LOG2Fc',
                y = 'statistic$p',
                xlim = c(-3, 3),
                title = 'Group 4 Medulloblastoma vs Non Tumoral',
                subtitle = "Volcano Plot by EnhancedVolcano",
                legendLabels=c('Not sig.','Log (base 2) FC','p-value',
                               'p-value & Log (base 2) FC'),
                pCutoff = 0.01,
                pCutoffCol = "statistic$p.adj",
                FCcutoff = 0.58,
                pointSize = 2.5,
                labCol = 'black',
                labFace = 'bold',
                labSize = 3.0,
                boxedLabels = TRUE,
                colAlpha = 4/5,
                col=c("grey", "green4", "blue4",  "red3"),
                legendIconSize = 4.0,
                drawConnectors = TRUE,
                widthConnectors = 0.3,
                colConnectors = 'black', 
                max.overlaps = 30)
dev.off()
```

Thank you guys

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  here, we need you data as well as your code.  Please edit your question to include the output from `dput(data)` (or `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: ...that's a lot of columns we don't want a full `dput()`. I'd suggest `dput(your_data[1:10, 1:5])` for the first 10 rows and first 5 columns. (Make sure the `design.design` column is included.) Or perhaps use a built-in data set. (@Limey I'd be more careful asking for `dput()`s especially from new users who evidently have 300+ column data sets.)

Comment: Typically functions involved in genomics need to adjust t- and p- values to account for the serious multiple comparisons issues. Your question does not indicate whether you are aware of these issues.

Comment: More generally, `ggpubr` is meant to provide some easy ways to adds stats to plots, but I wouldn't rely on it to actually perform my analyses. For RNA-seq data, I would a package meant for that purpose, something like `DESeq2`.

Comment: Hello to all. Already edited my question. Hope is better now and I'll wait for your considerations! Thank you